# How to get only objects of one type from an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parsing

(Xcode IOS) - I'm trying to make a method which prefetches all the images and loads them into a tableView before scrolling (using SDWebImage). Anyways:

I have an array of `messages` and each "message" is composed of a few different keys, `PFFile`, `dateCreated`, `sender`, etc...

What I need to do is take this array of `@[ [PFFile], [dateCreated], [other info] ] -> @[ [PFFile] ]`

In other words, I need to make an array of just the `PFFiles` from the entire array. I was thinking of something like this (pseudocode)

`self.urls = [self.messages objectsWithKey:@[PFFiles]];`

Comment: Since you're using an array, what do you mean by keys in here? More specifically what are the objects in your array?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking how to filter an array.

```
self.urls = [self.messages objectsAtIndexes:[self.messages indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[PFFile class]];
}]];
```

I like this syntax because you can use a block to return YES/NO if the object passes any sort of test you might want to write and it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

How about using combination of NSDictionary and NSArray ?
You can put your array objects in a dictionary object.